# What does r-globalnav-height mean in a css file

Tags: css

I have seen a site styling

```
html
{
  --r-globalnav-height: 44px;
}
```

what does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is CSS variable. It can contain specific values to be used multiple times in a style sheets.

You can then use the variable from your example as follows:

```css
nav {
  height: var(--r-globalnav-height); /* height: 44px */
}
```

You can read more at [Using CSS custom properties (variables) - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)